# Error When Trying to Create a New Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just downloaded **ADT Bundle for Windows 64**, which comes with **Eclipse + ADT plugin**, **Android SDK Tools** and so on... when I try to create a new Android project, right after the screen where I choose the **Blank Activity template**, the following error message is displayed:

**Unsupported template dependency: Upgrade your Android Eclipse plugin**

in this same screen is informed that this template depends on the **Android Support Library**... and right below there are 2 buttons, one for **Install/Upgrade** and the other one for **Check Again**. none of those buttons work. I've already done the necessary updates in **Help/Check for Updates** and **Help/Instal New Softwares**, in Eclipse. I've also done the necessary updates in **SDK Manager**. none of those updates fixed the problem. can someone help me with this deal?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What version of Android SDK Tools do you have?

Comment: Please, upload the screenshot of the problem..

Comment: my Android SDK version is 22.2.0 and my Eclipse version is 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these: (on Eclipse) File>>new>>project>>Android>>Android Application Project

If this can't be helpful, follow again these steps and when choose Android, you may see "?" icon on the left-down side.

If this can't be helpful again, try to use Eclipse older versions or verify that you are downloading x64 one. Also, try ADT-Plugin's .rar file from developer.android.com site and use older one to download.

These should be helpful for you.

Comment: Firstly, I run Eclipse x64 version, because my Windows is 64bit. Then, I run Eclipse x32 version. I didn't work anyway. On both cases, I installed all the repositories available for download in Eclipse. I also installed all the tools and extras and some of the APIs that I want to work with in SDK Manager. It didn't fix the problem. I don't know whatelse to try.

Comment: how can I download older versions of Eclipse or Android SDK Manager?

Comment: For Eclipse older download: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2
For ADT-Plugin older ones: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html

Comment: Bay, the problem was solved when I updated the Android SDK Tools. When I posted this question, Android SDK Tools version was 22.2, now, it is 22.2.1. I also had to update Eclipse plugins. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: Okey Thor, You're welcome.

Comment: Bay. Now, I noticed that the emulators are not running at all. Did you have the same problem? What now? Can you help me again?

Comment: Let me make a revise regarding the last post. It loads, I can see the screen with the icons but, when I try some options, it says: "Launcher has stopped".

Comment: Maybe because of your emulator's RAM capacity lowness, you can increase your virtual device's RAM. I know, emulator is working slowly, I connect my phone 4.2.2 to my Eclipse, when I click on RUN it starts up on my phone directly. 

Android virtula device manager(click on that icon on the top side of your eclipse)>>choose your device that before you did create>>On memory options>>RAM 512 or 1024 that you have what is that.

If you have mobile phone, on your phone, please active debugging on your options menu. Go your eclipse project>>right click>>run as>>run configuration>>click on target bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add more repositories to your Eclipse.
I am not sure..But try adding this repositories before updating..
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

**UPDATED**

Download from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip, unzip it and replace the /tools folder with this one to downgrade the sdk tools. There's a bug in version 22.

Comment: As I said for the user Bay, I installed all the repositories available for download in Eclipse. I also installed all the tools and extras and some of the APIs that I want to work with in SDK Manager. The problem still persists.

Comment: [link](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)
Here you can download older versions of Eclipse
Since You asked.@ThorMy See my Updated answer..

Comment: Augustus, the problem was solved when I updated the Android SDK Tools. When I posted this question, Android SDK Tools version was 22.2, now, it is 22.2.1. I also had to update Eclipse plugins. Thanks a lot for your assistance.